# When to use Quick Find and when to use Quick Union

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I know that Quick Union will always be faster than Quick Find, so what is the point of using Quick Find? I had an interview question that suggested to use Quick Find to solve the problem. Why did it not suggest quick union. Are there some cases where Quick Find would be optimal?

Comment: How is a quick union better? Isnt quick find faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the problem, it could be that finding if two nodes are connected is equally or more important than performing the actual connection.  Quick Find's connection check has O(1) complexity, while Quick Union's connection check has O(N) complexity.

Comment: Ah. This may have been it. It was suggested  to look for a connection, not to form one. Thanks, I was wracking my brain over it.